# Marshalling struct array of dynamic size?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmarshalling

Is it possible to Marshal an struct array of dynamic size like so? I'm trying to send data over a network and instead of, in this example, sending 5 different packets containing one testStruct each (which I'm able to do just fine and it works) I would like to group those packets for efficiency into one packet of sendTestStruct containing an array of 5 testStructs.

```
public struct sendTestStruct
{
    public int numberOfStructs;
    public testStruct[] structs;
}
public struct testStruct 
{
    public float float1, float2;
    public int int1, int2;
    public byte byte1, byte2;
}

sendTestStruct send = new();
send.structs = new testStruct[5];
send.numberOfStructs = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    testStruct numbers = new();
    numbers.float1 = Random.Range(0f, 10f);
    numbers.float2 = Random.Range(0f, 10f);
    numbers.int1 = Random.Range(0, 10);
    numbers.int2 = Random.Range(0, 10);
    numbers.byte1 = (byte)Random.Range(0, 10);
    numbers.byte2 = (byte)Random.Range(0, 10);
    send.structs[i] = numbers;
}
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(send));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(send, ptr, false);

sendTestStruct newstruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<sendTestStruct>(ptr);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

But I get an error

> Structure field of type testStruct[] can't be marshalled as LPArray

Is there a way to do this?

The error happens when trying to do
sendTestStruct newstruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr);

Comment: What does `Marshal.SizeOf(send)` return?

Comment: The array needs the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)] attribute so it doesn't get turned into a pointer with memory management headaches.  This isn't actually efficient, but you'd never see the difference since network latencies are so high.

Comment: @BenVoigt Now that you mention it, it was returning 24 which was clearly wrong since each testStruct should be at least 18 with a total of 5 structs

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I don't get that error anymore, however when trying to read the "unpacked" array its size is just 1, not 5. I can read the values of unpacked structs[0] just fine though. Is there a way to work around this since I can't know the size of the array on runtime?

Also, could you expand on not being efficient, since this is actually for a game and latency is very important, would there be any other way?

Comment: Right, it doesn't know the size of the array when converting back from unmanaged memory.  That requires [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=5)].  Not dynamic.  The only other way to do it is work from the IntPtr and call Marshal.PtrToStruct() for each element in the array.

Comment: @theepic0: Basically you won't be able to use the `Marshal` class to do the work for you, you'll need to write a loop to copy each instance over.  Would be really nice if `Buffer.BlockCopy` didn't give up as soon as it noticed an aggregate type.... there's no technical reason it couldn't copy arrays of structures of primitives just as safely as arrays of primitives.

Comment: So hilariously, it actually ends up being easiest to write a `DllImport` for the C library `memcpy`.

Comment: @HansPassant I actually thought about doing that, but I don't know how to put that in code. I tried managing IntPtr[5] but obviously I run into the same problem of not knowing the array size on runtime. Any advice on how would I call PtrToStruct() in a loop?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the idea actually, if I can't get this to work using structures I'll just send primitives